# Spring XWSS Message Signing

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws, ws-security

I am currently working on a client interface which connects to a third party web service.

This 3rd party web service requires that all messages sent to them are signed with the client's private key.

I am attempting to implement this using Spring's XWSS support as documented here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html

The issue I'm facing is that the messages I send out are not being signed despite what as far as I can tell is a correct configuration.

My applicationContext.xml is as follows:

```
<beans 
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">

    ^
    |
    |
    B
    E
    A
    N
    S
    |
    |
    V

    <bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor"
         class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
         <property name="policyConfiguration" value="classpath:securityPolicy.xml"/>
         <property name="callbackHandlers">
            <list>
               <ref bean="keyStoreHandler"/>
            </list>
         </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="keyStoreHandler"
         class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.KeyStoreCallbackHandler">
         <property name="keyStore" ref="keyStore"/>
         <property name="privateKeyPassword" value="ckpass"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="keyStore"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="file:///C:/path/to/security/clientKeystore.jks"/>
        <property name="password" value="cspass"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My securityPolicy.xml consists of the following:

```
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration dumpMessages="true" xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config">
    <xwss:Sign>
   </xwss:Sign>
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

However there are no messages being dumped to standard output when I send messages out and the messages I send out do not contain the signature elements I would expect.

I suspect I am missing something quite trivial here however I cannot tell what that is for the life of me!

Comment: So you have an interceptor and where have you wired it to your `WebServiceTemplate`? Judging from the configuration you only have configured it and now it just sits there.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance - I am new to Spring - what is it that you referring to when talking about wiring the interceptor to a WebServiceTemplate?

The Spring documentation says the following before defining the wsSecurityInterceptor bean:

_Here is an example that shows how to wire the XwsSecurityInterceptor up:_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your configuration you only configure the interceptor. Currently it takes up only memory just hanging around and doing nothing. You should hook this interceptor up to your `WebServiceTemplate` (or class that extends `WebServiceGatewaySupport`.

Assuming you have one of those you should have something like this.

```
<bean id="yourClient" class="YourClientClass">
    <property name="interceptors" ref="wsSecurityInterceptor"/>
    // Your other properties here
</bean>
```

This wired your interceptor to the `WebServiceTemplate` used, without it the interceptor is basically not used.

Comment: Thankyou for your help.

I do not appear to have anything along the lines of WebServiceTemplate or WebServiceGatewaySupport however I think I may be looking in the wrong area with this question!

Part of the client is implemented using Apache CXF so perhaps it is in this area I should be looking to sign the messages and not using Spring Web Services!

I followed this trail as I had to set up the SSL security for the transport layer in Spring.

This is my first time using Spring and my first time using CXF - hence my confusion.

Comment: If you are using Apache CXF for your web-services then trying to use the Spring Web Service infrastructure to secure the clients isn't going to work. You will have to use the Apache CXF infrastructure for this (or refactor your code to use Spring Web Services).

Comment: Understood - apologies for the misunderstanding.

Marking the answer as correct as I believe it does answer the question as asked- my problem being my question wasn't what it should have been!