# spring webclient sign a body request

Tags: java, spring, webclient, reactive

I am in the need to sign a body request send out with WebClient in Spring.

Now, the problem it's that i am not able to get the body in "raw" way (the exact body that get sent to remote server) and calculate the signature from this body.

I have two scenario, a post of an object and post a FormData.
on the 1st i can probably use an ObjectMapper, to mimic what WebClient does (till WebClient change it, and everything break) but for FormData, mimic it will be tricky.

If i send
a = b, e = x
i have to deal with encoding, and order of parameter (from http point of view) it's not mandatory so a=b, e=x it's the same of e=x,a=b but that's not true for a signature where sha1(string) change

With filter i get the body() but it's a BodyInserter and it doesn't seems that it can be converted into a String or byte[]

Comment: Have you checked [xwss message signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526767/spring-xwss-message-signing)

Answer (score 2):

Signing the body would require it in serialized form, but serialization happens just before sending the data so it needs to be intercepted.

Making an assumption that you are sending your data as JSON, you can do this by creating your own JsonEncoder (wrapping the existing `Jackson2JsonEncoder` for example) and passing this as an `ExchangeStrategies` when building the `WebClient`. After the serialized data is intercepted, you can inject the headers. But the Encoder does not have a reference to the `ClientHttpRequest` so you will need to capture this object in an `HttpConnector` and pass it in the `SubscriberContext`.

The `BodyInserters` automatically pick message writers to write messages, and in the case of encoding/serialization (like Json) this gets handed off the codecs like the wrapping Encoder I'm suggesting.
(If you're not sending JSON, please let us know what format because the solution will be different for other content-types, like url-encoded forms etc.)

This blog post explains the process: https://andrew-flower.com/blog/Custom-HMAC-Auth-with-Spring-WebClient#s-post-data-signing

As an example, your `WebClient` creation step might look like below, where `MessageCapturingHttpConnector` is a connector that captures the `ClientHttpRequest` and `BodyCapturingJsonEncoder`

```
Signer signer = new Signer(clientId, secret);
MessageSigningHttpConnector httpConnector = new MessageSigningHttpConnector();
BodyCapturingJsonEncoder bodyCapturingJsonEncoder
    = new BodyCapturingJsonEncoder(signer);

WebClient client
    = WebClient.builder()
               .exchangeFunction(ExchangeFunctions.create(
                       httpConnector,
                       ExchangeStrategies
                              .builder()
                               .codecs(clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer -> {
                                   clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(bodyCapturingJsonEncoder);
                                   clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(new ObjectMapper(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                               })
                               .build()
               ))
               .baseUrl(String.format("%s://%s/%s", environment.getProtocol(), environment.getHost(), environment.getPath()))
               .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
               .build();
```